# check one CSV is contained in another CSV column in database LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, csv

I have a table called `Products` having column called `ApprovedState` which contains values like `"AL,AK,AR"`. I'm getting a CSV list from front-end as `listCSVState='AL,AK'`.

Can someone help me to write a LINQ query which will return me all products which are approved in `listCSVState`. I have tried following code but not getting the correct result.

```
from product in db.Products where ((listCSVState== null) || (listCSVState.Contains(product.StateApprovals)))
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: from product in db.Products where ((state == null) || (listCSVState.Contains(product.StateApprovals)))

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting the code in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mangesh:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial in LINQ to Objects, tricky in LINQ to Entities due to lack of `string.Split` support.

Still, a combination of `Any`, `string.Contains` and string concatenations can do the job, like this

```
var states = listCSVState.Split(',');
var query = db.Products.Where(product => states.Any(state =>
    ("," + product.StateApprovals + ",").Contains("," + state + ",")));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Ivan but I am not getting any results when some state in  listCSVState does not exists in database column StateApprovals. eg: listCSVState='AL,AK,IA' but I am not getting those products which are available in AL,AK but not in IA. It seems your solution is checking that all stated should be included but i only want one of them.

Comment: By idea it should do exactly what you want. Check again (and make sure there are no spaces before or after commas). `states.Any` means at least one match, otherwise I would have used `states.All`.

Comment: You are correct , It was some typo mistake in which I was putting listCSVState instead of state. Thanks for helping me out.